# Thumb image in retina not working in UISlider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uislider

I am working on UISlider in which i have added a Thumb image (slider_iphone.png 53 X 199) over the slider.[image: without retina image] But the problem is When i add retina image(slider_iphone@2x.png 106 X 398), the thumb image becomes very wider and longer than the simple image.[image: with retina]

I have searched a lot over google and stack overflow but didn't find any solution. Why is it not taking the retina image in correct frame. Please suggest any solution.

**Code:**

```
slider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,180.0,320.0,180.0)];

[slider setMinimumValue:1.0f];

[slider setMaximumValue:10.0f];

[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderMoved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UIImage *sliderTrackImage1 = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"button-transparent.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 0.0 topCapHeight: 0.0];

UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_iphone@2x.png"];

[slider setMinimumTrackImage: sliderTrackImage1 forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage: sliderTrackImage1 forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setThumbImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[slider setThumbImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: dont use retina image for thumb or slider min and max, use normal images, of if possible use stretchable images. they will do the task

Comment: Thanks for reply but the client is asking why we can't use retina image for this

Comment: because the size of thumb will not increase with your image, it has some fix size, you can read more about it on apple documentation or search on google, you will get answer, and though you are not convinced, i insist to use stretchable image.

Comment: what is these streachable images?

Comment: have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=250) for more detail about it, good luck

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help. Actually it works by removing the normal image from the project and adding the retina image after removing @2x from the name. I don't know how but it's picking the retina image in proper dimension now. Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the @2x image defined in code!

Have both the normal image and the @2x image in your bundle and in code specify the normal image!

The app will appropriately select what image it needs depending on device's screen.

Comment: i have done that but it is not picking the retina image. But the thing is that what should i say why it's not showing retina image?

Answer (score 2):

No need to add @2x just use this like :

```
[self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"n.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: i have done the same. But it's not picking retina image. I want to use retina image.

Comment: Ok.that is a problem.if you think you don't require the normal image then you can just remove the normal image and keep retina only.

Comment: Than it become longer and wider as given in above image.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help. Actually it works by removing the normal image from the project and adding the retina image after removing @2x from the name. I don't know how but it's picking the retina image in proper dimension now. Thanks....

Comment: Congrats,Now you have what you want.Happy coding...
To Check more visit : dcraziee.wordpress.com